# R: Loop to capture weather data from multiple station

Tags: r, rwunderground

I wanted to perform loop to capture weather data from multiple stations using code below:

```
library(rwunderground)

sample_df <- data.frame(airportid = c("K6A2",
                                      "KAPA",
                                      "KASD",
                                      "KATL",
                                      "KBKF",
                                      "KBKF",
                                      "KCCO",
                                      "KDEN",
                                      "KFFC",
                                      "KFRG"),
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

history_range(set_location(airport_code =sample_df$airportid), date_start = "20170815", date_end = "20170822",
              limit = 10, no_api = FALSE, use_metric = FALSE, key = get_api_key(),
              raw = FALSE, message = TRUE)
```

It won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you are passing the entire vector (multiple character values) into the `history_range` call. Simply `lapply` to iteratively pass the vector values and even return a list of `history_range()` return objects. Below uses a defined function to pass the parameter. Extend the function as needed to perform other operations.

```
capture_weather_data <- function(airport_id) {
    data <- history_range(set_location(airport_code=airport_id), 
                  date_start = "20170815", date_end = "20170822",
                  limit = 10, no_api = FALSE, use_metric = FALSE, key = get_api_key(),
                  raw = FALSE, message = TRUE)

    write.csv(data, paste0("/path/to/output/", airport_id, ".csv"))
    return(data)
}

data_list <- lapply(sample_df$airportid, capture_weather_data)
```

Also, name each item in list to the corresponding *airport_id* character value:

```
data_list <- setNames(data_list, sample_df$airportid)

data_list$K6A2   # 1st ITEM
data_list$KAPA   # 2nd ITEM
data_list$KASD   # 3rd ITEM
...
```

---

In fact, with `sapply` (the wrapper to `lapply`) you can generate list and name each item in same call but the input vector must be a character type (not factor):

```
data_list <- sapply(as.character(sample_df$airportid), capture_weather_data, 
                    simplify=FALSE, USE.NAMES=TRUE)
names(data_list)
```

Comment: Thank you again for your help. As a final question, how can I save it as csv file or the others?

Comment: I do not know what the API returns. If a dataframe/matrix, see extended function in above update adding in `write.csv`.

Comment: The csv file was created within the designated location but no data was in it. For single station, I could see the data within R  Studio, meaning table form(?)

Answer (score 0):

I think this history_range function that you brought up, from the rwunderground package as I understand, requires a weather underground API key. I went to the site and even signed up for it, but the email validation process in order to get a key (https://www.wunderground.com/weather/api) doesn't seem to be working correctly at the moment.

Instead I went to the CRAN mirror (https://github.com/cran/rwunderground/blob/master/R/history.R) and from what I understand, the function accepts only one string as set_location argument. The example provided in the documentation is

```
history(set_location(airport_code = "SEA"), "20130101")
```

So what you should be doing as a "loop", instead, is

```
sample_df <- as.vector(sample_df)
for(i in 1:length(sample_df)){
  history_range(
    set_location(airport_code = sample_df[[i]]), 
    date_start = "20170815", date_end = "20170822",
    limit = 10, no_api = FALSE, use_metric = FALSE, 
    key = get_api_key(),
    raw = FALSE, message = TRUE)
}
```

If this doesn't work, let me know. (Ack, somebody also gave another answer to this question while I was typing this up.)

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try to do with your guidance.